# How to print class attributes of dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary

> I am trying to access the content for every node in a dictionary I am
>   making but am not sure how to proceed. For example given the two nodes
>   in the dictionary I would hope to print out the letter M and H.

```
class Node:
      def __init__(self, content):
        self.content = content

def createLattice():
    Node1 = Node("M")
    Node2 = Node("H")

    lattice = {Node1: [Node2],
         Node2: [Node1]}

    for key in lattice:
         print(key.content())
```

Comment: Attribute is not a function: `print(key.content)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating your init function this way

```
def __init__(self, content):
    self.content = content
```

And create your object like this

```
Node1 = Node("M")
Node2 = Node("H")
```

You are assigning `content` as a `str`, e.g "H".

So when you access it, it is a string, not a function. You cannot use it as `key.content()`. But use:

```
key.content
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Node:
      def __init__(self, content):
        self.content = content

def createLattice():
    Node1 = Node("M")
    Node2 = Node("H")

    lattice = {Node1: [Node2],
         Node2: [Node1]}

    for key in lattice:
         print(key.content)

createLattice()
```

You were accessing an attribute of a class as it were a method! `Node.content` isn't a method, it's an attribute, so you refer to it as `Node.content`, not `Node.content()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content = content


def createLattice():
    Node1 = Node("M")
    Node2 = Node("H")

    lattice = {Node1: [Node2],
               Node2: [Node1]}

    for key,value in lattice.items():
        print(key.content)
        print(value[0].content)


createLattice()
```

Hope this helps. Note that content shouldn't be called with () as it's an attribute not a method. To access the key, value or both in dict, you will need to get them through key(), value() or items().